# Alias a table (read/write view)

Tags: postgresql

I'm wondering if it's possible in postgresql to create an additional name for a table, such that the table can be referred to by either its new alias or the original name?

Like adding a view for the table, but which writes to the underlying table when you update or insert on the 'view'.

The purpose of this is to be able to rename a table without having to update all of the db clients at once (no downtime).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Postgres RULES to do this.

Check out [this](http://legitimatesounding.com/blog/Stupid_PostgreSQL_Tricks%3a_Writable_Views.html) article.

Comment: For Pg 9.1 and above use a view trigger in preference to a rule where possible. It's *way* easier to get right.

Comment: @CraigRinger I tried the view triggers as described here: 
http://www.depesz.com/2010/10/16/waiting-for-9-1-triggers-on-views/
but, when e.g. an insert fails, the error is not propagated to the client.

Comment: @WillHartung as Craig Ringer pointed out, those RULES are actually quite tricky, particularly the fact that you need to have a WHERE clause on the UPDATE to pick out the primary key... what if the UPDATE statement you are applying has some other criteria?  This is way too dangerous for me for what should be a simple alias.

Comment: @EoghanM View triggers should work. Very weird that the error doesn't make it to the client. Or, when you say "error" do you mean "row count = 0"? The row count is not returned with a view trigger, rules are still the only way to do that. Exceptions are propagated unless you catch them with `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION` block.

Comment: @EoghanM Try updating your question with the *full text of the SQL executed* and the *exact text of the error message*, or post a new question on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

@CraigRinger mentions [this answer](http://www.depesz.com/2010/10/16/waiting-for-9-1-triggers-on-views/):

```
CREATE VIEW alias_as_view as SELECT * FROM original_table;


CREATE FUNCTION write_to_underlying_table() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' then
    raise notice 'INSERT trigger, NEW = [%]', NEW;
ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' then
    raise notice 'UPDATE trigger, OLD = [%], NEW = [%]', OLD, NEW;
ELSE
    raise notice 'DELETE trigger, OLD = [%]', OLD;
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER view_writable_trigger INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE 
      ON alias_as_view FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE write_to_underlying_table();
```

I've rejected it for the moment as e.g. a failing query:

```
INSERT INTO alias_as_view VALUES ('existing_key', 'some_value');
```

Seems to have executed successfully, even though the actual INSERT statement on `original_table` failed due to a unique key violation.